# SQL Server Update & Replace Spam in "text" and "ntext" fields

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, iis-7

First and foremost, thank you for your time by taking a look at this issue.

An old database table has over 14k spam links injected into it, many of which are in text and ntext fields.  I have written a SQL query which runs and updates any fields that are not "text" or "ntext" type, however it unfortunately does not update the "text" or "ntext" fields at all.

Brief information about the database: it is running on IIS7, is SQL Server 2008, and PHP is enabled (version 5.3).  Unfortunately I have VERY limited capability to update the database directly or from a control panel (otherwise this would have been handled swiftly) so I am writing this script in PHP to automatically update compromised tables.  The script in this form runs without error, however I do not have any updates in the text or ntext fields.

The script is as follows:

```
//Basic DB Connection
$conn = database_info;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages_test_only";  
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

//Loop to scrub each table
foreach(sqlsrv_field_metadata($result) as $fieldMetadata) 
{
    //The loop here updates each section of spam (starting with </title>) with "" (empty/null)
    //and leaves other content intact.  The double quotes in the spam are escaped (\").

    //Text update - if the field type is 'text'
    if ($fieldMetadata['Type'] == -1) 
    { 
    $sqlupdate = "UPDATE pages_test_only SET ".$fieldMetadata['Name']." = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(".$fieldMetadata['Name']." as nvarchar(6000)), '</title><div style=\"display:block; text-indent:-5670px;\"><a href=\"http://buy-cialis-onlineusa.com\">generic cialis</a></div>', '') AS text";
    }
    //Ntext update - if the field type is 'ntext'
    elseif ($fieldMetadata['Type'] == -10) 
    { 
    $sqlupdate = "UPDATE pages_test_only SET ".$fieldMetadata['Name']." = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(".$fieldMetadata['Name']." as nvarchar(6000)), '</title><div style=\"display:block; text-indent:-5670px;\"><a href=\"http://buy-cialis-onlineusa.com\">generic cialis</a></div>', '') AS ntext";
    }
    //Any other update - if the field contains the spam, but is of any other type [this is working]
    else
    {
    $sqlupdate = "UPDATE pages_test_only SET ".$fieldMetadata['Name']." = REPLACE(".$fieldMetadata['Name'].", '</title><div style=\"display:block; text-indent:-5670px;\"><a href=\"http://buy-cialis-onlineusa.com\">generic cialis</a></div>', '')";
    }

    //Send to DB
    $res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlupdate);

}
```

I am aware that converting the text and ntext fields into nvarchar permanently would be ideal, however for these purposes I need the table structure to remain as is when the script completes.

Additionally, if you know of a way to pull in column metadata without having to SELECT everything in SQL Server 2008, I would greatly appreciate this information as it will speed up my query for the actual table.

Please let me know what issues you see, and again thank you very much for your time.

**Edit:**

While the major issue still exists, I was able to pull in only the field name and type with this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'pages_test_only'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
```

It is applied in a while loop:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['COLUMN_NAME']."<br />";
    echo $row['DATA_TYPE']."<br />";

    //update - text type
    if ($row['DATA_TYPE'] == 'text') 
    { 
    echo "This column is a text column.<br />";
    $sqlupdate = "UPDATE pages_test_only SET ".$row['COLUMN_NAME']." = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(".$row['COLUMN_NAME']." as nvarchar(1000)), '</title><div style=\"display:block; text-indent:-5670px;\"><a href=\"http://buy-cialis-onlineusa.com\">generic cialis</a></div>', 'test') AS text";
    }
    //update - ntext type 
    elseif ($row['DATA_TYPE'] == 'ntext') 
    { 
    echo "This column is a ntext column.<br />";
    $sqlupdate = "UPDATE pages_test_only SET ".$row['COLUMN_NAME']." = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(".$row['COLUMN_NAME']." as nvarchar(1000)), '</title><div style=\"display:block; text-indent:-5670px;\"><a href=\"http://buy-cialis-onlineusa.com\">generic cialis</a></div>', 'test') AS ntext";
    }
    //update - any other type
    else
    {
    $sqlupdate = "UPDATE pages_test_only SET ".$row['COLUMN_NAME']." = REPLACE(".$row['COLUMN_NAME'].", '</title><div style=\"display:block; text-indent:-5670px;\"><a href=\"http://buy-cialis-onlineusa.com\">generic cialis</a></div>', 'test')";
    }
$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlupdate);
}
```

Comment: It looks good to me. The one bit of advice I'll offer you is to backup the database before you try to clean it up.

Comment: I felt the same - I thought the queries looked good, however the text and ntext updates do nothing at all.  I'm wondering if the spam string is not configured properly, or if there is something more I have to do with the CAST operator.

Comment: It might be worth using sqlsrv_error to check if an error is being reported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit embarrassed, but the issue I was having was syntax.  I forgot a parenthesis on the end of each SQL statement.  That being said, here is the 
final, working set of updates:

```
//basic connection information
$serverName = "dbhost.etc"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"db_name", "UID"=>"db_user", "PWD"=>"db_pass");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

//connection check
if( $conn ) 
{
 echo "Connection established.<br /><br />";
}
else
{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

//this selects ONLY the column name and type from the table
$sql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

//a loop is set up for each column that checks for data type and casts/updates accordingly
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{

    //update - text type
    if ($row['DATA_TYPE'] == 'text') 
    { 
    $sqlupdate = "UPDATE table_name SET ".$row['COLUMN_NAME']." = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(".$row['COLUMN_NAME']." as nvarchar(max)), 'string', 'replacement') AS text)";
    }
    //update - ntext type 
    elseif ($row['DATA_TYPE'] == 'ntext') 
    { 
    $sqlupdate = "UPDATE table_name SET ".$row['COLUMN_NAME']." = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(".$row['COLUMN_NAME']." as nvarchar(max)), 'string', 'replacement') AS ntext)";
    }
    //update - any other type
    else
    {
    $sqlupdate = "UPDATE table_name SET ".$row['COLUMN_NAME']." = REPLACE(".$row['COLUMN_NAME'].", 'string', 'replacement')";
    }


    $res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlupdate);

}
```